# Elasticsearch 6.3.1 collapse based on two fields

Tags: elasticsearch

My database looks something like :

```
[
  {
    "header": {
      "date": "2021-11-01 22:16:48",
      "net_name": "a",
      "batch_size": 8,
      "result": 50
    }
  },
  {
    "header": {
      "date": "2021-11-02 22:16:48",
      "net_name": "a",
      "batch_size": 8,
      "result": 1000
    }
  },
  {
    "header": {
      "date": "2021-11-02 22:16:48",
      "net_name": "a",
      "batch_size": 12,
      "result": 1000
    }
  },
  {
    "header": {
      "date": "2021-11-01 22:16:48",
      "net_name": "b",
      "batch_size": 8,
      "result": 1000
    }
  },
  {
    "header": {
      "date": "2021-11-02 22:16:48",
      "net_name": "b",
      "batch_size": 12,
      "result": 1000
    }
  },
  {
    "header": {
      "date": "2021-11-01 22:16:48",
      "net_name": "b",
      "batch_size": 12,
      "result": 50
    }
  }
]
```

I am using Elasticsearch, and I need a query that returns the latest documents of each combination of net_name + batch_size (collapse based on these two fields)

i.e I want the result to be

```
net_name,batch_size,result
"a",8,1000
"a",12,1000
"b",8,1000
"b",12,1000
```

I tried to use the "collapse" option but I didn't find how to collapse based on a combination of two fields

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

what i understand you mean is that get max time value when collapse based on net_name,batch_size.
for example:

```
{
 "sort":[{"header.net_name":"asc"}],
 "collapse":{
   "field":"header.net_name",
   "inner_hits":{
      "name":"somename",
      "collapse":"header.batch_size",
      "sort":[{"header.date":"desc"}]   
   }
 }
}
```

1. sort by net_name
2. collapse by net_name
3. sort by date
4. collapse by batch_size
   you will get what you want.

Comment: I am using version 6.3.1 and it seems like it does not support "collapse" inside "inner_fields", when i try it i get "[inner_hits] unknown field [collapse], parser not found" error. can you think of another way to do that?